# applescript to move files from folder A to folder B with excel list

Tags: excel, applescript

I have a folder of PDFs, around 650. And I have a excel list containing a list of PDFs I have to merge them into a single PDF.

I found this script:

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    tell active sheet
        set fileList to value of used range
        tell used range
            set rc to count of rows
        end tell
    end tell
end tell

set rootFolder to "/Users/aldoopenhouse/Desktop/EN ATTENTE/test cahier de details/Master Detail Book/PDF" as POSIX file
set filesToMove to {}

repeat with thisItem in fileList
    try
        set end of filesToMove to alias (rootFolder & thisItem)
    on error
        display dialog "File " & thisItem & " is not in the folder"
    end try
end repeat

tell application "Finder"
    move filesToMove to folder "/Users/aldoopenhouse/Desktop/EN ATTENTE/test cahier de details/*RESULT" as POSIX file
end tell
```

and this script always retourn the result : `file *********.pdf` is not in the folder

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your folder is "PDF" inside folder "Master Detail Book". when you concat rootFolder and ThisItem, the separator ":" is missing.

What you try to add at end of filestoMove is "Users:aldoopenhouse:Desktop:EN ATTENTE:test cahier de details:Master Detail Book:PDFthisitem"

Where is should be "Users:aldoopenhouse:Desktop:EN ATTENTE:test cahier de details:Master Detail Book:PDF:thisitem"  (added the ":")

Then instruction should be :

```
set end of filesToMove to alias (rootFolder & ":" & thisItem)
```

Also you may have an issue if your Excel file contains file names without extensions (only visible names).

Comment: my Excel file contains filename + extension, I fixer that issue earlier before posting here. As for the rest, I still get the same msg. Is this an issue using "/" instead of ":" ?

Answer (score 0):

You also have alias issues. So I update your script and it is now working for me (of course, I changed the paths to match my user/folder names for testing, but I set them back)

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
tell active sheet
    set fileList to value of used range
    tell used range
        set rc to count of rows
    end tell
end tell
end tell

set rootFolder to "Users:aldoopenhouse:Desktop:EN ATTENTE:test cahier de details:Master Detail Book:PDF"
set filesToMove to {}

repeat with thisItem in fileList
try
    set end of filesToMove to (rootFolder & ":" & thisItem) as alias
on error
    display dialog "File " & thisItem & " is not in the folder"
end try
end repeat
tell application "Finder"
move filesToMove to folder (("Users:aldoopenhouse:Desktop:EN ATTENTE:test cahier de details:*RESULT") as alias)
end tell
```

I simplified the paths to always use Finder form.

Last comment, I don't like folder *RESULT. I recommend to never use special characters like "*" in folder/file names. Especially "*" which is a generic char in Unix commands !

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is that `used range` in `Excel` returns a nested list, to get the inner items a second repeat loop is needed.

The Finder expects HFS paths (colon separated), the easiest way to get the HFS path to the current desktop is

```
path to desktop as text
```

Try this

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    tell active sheet
        tell used range
            set usedRange to value
            set rc to count of rows
        end tell
    end tell
end tell

set baseFolder to (path to desktop as text) & "EN ATTENTE:test cahier de details:"
set rootFolder to baseFolder & "Master Detail Book:PDF:"

set filesToMove to {}

repeat with fileList in usedRange
    repeat with thisItem in fileList
        try
            set end of filesToMove to alias (rootFolder & thisItem)
        on error
            display dialog "File " & thisItem & " is not in the folder"
        end try
    end repeat
end repeat

tell application "Finder"
    move filesToMove to folder (baseFolder & "*RESULT:")
end tell
```